# Angular MatTable not updating on PUTs

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I have a parent table that is meant to be reusable by just inputting a datasource. Components that want to use this table should have a service injection that provides `Observable`s for the parent table to consume. as such, I expect any components to need to implement one or more of the HTTP Verbs, Get,Put,Post,Delete. I want these actions to be reflected in the MatTable once they happen and a result is returned. The initial load of the table works fine, but whenever I do a PUT, I don't see the change reflected in the table. Can someone help me point to what I'm missing?`

parent-table (omissions, for clarity):

```
export class TableComponent {
  public tableDataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
  public displayedColumns: string[] = [];
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: false }) matPaginator?: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) matSort?: MatSort;

  @Input() set tableData(data: MatTableDataSource<any>) {
    this.setTableDataSource(data);

  constructor() {
     console.log("Hello")
  }

  setTableDataSource(data: MatTableDataSource<any>) {
    this.tableDataSource = data;
    if (this.matPaginator) {
      this.tableDataSource.paginator = this.matPaginator;
    }
    if (this.matSort) {
      this.tableDataSource.sort = this.matSort;
    }
  }
  }
```

Table is being used in another component like this:

```
    <app-data-table 
        [isFilterable]="true"
        [isSortable]="true"
        [isPageable]="true"
        [tableColumns]="customerColumns"
        [tableData]="customers"
        [rowActionIcon]="'more_vert'"
        [menuActions]="this.menuActions"
        (rowAction)="onTableAction($event)" 
        (sort)="sortData($event)"
        >
    </app-data-table>
```

The component looks like this:

```
export class CustomersComponent {
  customers;
  selectedCustomer: Customer | null;
  menuActions: MenuItemDefinition[];
  customerColumns: { name: string; dataKey: string; isSortable: boolean }[];
  constructor(private cust_api: CustomerApiService) {
    this.customers = new MatTableDataSource<Customer>([]);
   
  ngOnInit(): void {
    /** Issue GET call and bind the returning observable to the MatTableDataSource */
    this.cust_api.getCustomers().subscribe((customers) => {
      this.customers.data = customers;
    });
  }

  updateCustomer(customer: Customer): void {
     this.cust_api.updateCustomer(customer as Customer)
     .subscribe((updated_customer: Customer) => (customer = updated_customer));
  }
```

Whenever updateCustomer is called, the api call returns 200 and the content of the changed object in the backend, however the table is not updated. Do I need to change my updateCustomer method somehow, or how can I reflect that the datasource has additions without manually doing that? I thought the idea was to let the MatTableDatasource handle that?

EDIT:

I can get the table to update by directly interacting with the `this.customers.data` attribute:

```
  updateCustomer(customer: Customer): void {
    this.cust_api
      .updateCustomer(customer as Customer)
      .subscribe((updated_customer: Customer) => {
        const to_keep = this.customers.data.filter(
          (customer) => customer.id !== updated_customer.id
        );
        this.customers.data = [updated_customer, ...to_keep];
      });
  }
```

This will refresh the table and put the updated customer at the top - but it still feels hacky. I can't use [tableData]="customers | async" somehow?

Answer (score 1):

The "hacky" way that you refer is actually the "preferred way".

First, the reason you don't see it update is because you are mutating the object: *obj = {age: 1}, obj.age = 2*.  This is mutating. The obj **never changed** its reference in the eye of Angular.

The "hacky" way is update the reference obj = {age: 2}, this is a totally new object. I won't go into detail here as you will find many explanation on the internet about this. This is about Javascript, not specific about Angular.
The keyword is changing the reference, only changes lead to updating, no changes no update.

Back to the issue, you just need to update the reference of customer.data, that's it. And you did it already.

Now for the lifecycle hook of Angular:

- [OnChanges](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#using-change-detection-hooks): only trigger when input change, which in this case doesn't, as explained above => no use.
- [DoCheck](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#defining-custom-change-detection): Trigger whenever there's a change detection happen. Means it will trigger many, many, many times.

Edit: For the `async` pipe. This pipe helps you remove subscription in your component. This means you return observable instead of `.subscribe` in component.
Small example: customer$ = customerService.getAll(), your api returns observable so customer$ holds an observable, that's the "$" stands for, it's a common convention. Now in your template you could use customer$ | async.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation Jimmy, Currently my api_service only returns `Observables` for the child/concrete component to use. Do you suggest that the api_service keep track of the `state` (ie your getting/saving data) as well, or add another service that speaks with the api, and keeps track of the state of returned data?

Comment: oh yeah, my bad, you already has `CustomerApiService`, so my word for a separated service is incorrect, sorry.

Comment: No worries - just asking for clarification. This `CustomersComponent` now manages both the state of the data coming from the api, and making sure that the child table class is being refreshed. Do you think this separation is enough or should I add more layers ? x)

Comment: Yes and no, but I prefer no. The more layers the more abstract and abstraction sometimes makes it difficult to understand things. I prefer keeping things simple first. Then when you have problems, you know the pain, you will more appreciate advanced solutions such as design patterns or state management (ngrx, akita)